# Enforce inequality constraints R

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I have a function which I am using to calculate the sum of square differences between a 3 component normal mixture distribution function to a set of given quantiles. I want to use this function to optimize using the `Nelder-Mead` method in the `optim` function. The first 3 parameters to be optimized are mean parameters for the 3 components. The last 2 parameters are weight parameters for the components.

I already enforce that the parameters `w1` and `w2` are between 0 and 1 by using the inverse-logit function. Two other constraints that I want to enforce are `mean1 > mean2 > mean3` and `w1 + w2 + w3 = 1`. How can these constraints be enforced using this setup?

```
opt3 <- function(quantiles,levels,par) {
  mean1 <- par[1]
  mean2 <- par[2]
  mean3 <- par[3]
  w1 <- inv.logit(par[4])
  w2 <- inv.logit(par[5])
  w3 <- 1 - (w1+w2)
  
  sum((pnorm(quantiles,mean1,sd)*w1 + 
             pnorm(quantiles,mean2,sd)*w2 +
             pnorm(quantiles,mean3,sd)*w3 -
             levels)^2)
  
}


optim(par=par, opt3, quantiles=quantiles, levels=levels)
```

Comment: To constrain `mean1 > mean2` you could set `mean1 = mean2 + a` and use an optimization procedure allowing to set some bounds on the parameters, here `a > 0`. Or instead of setting some bounds you can set `mean1 = mean2 + exp(a)` for example.

Comment: And for the constraints on the `wi` you could do `w1 <- exp(-par[4])` and `w2 <- (1-w1)*exp(-par[5])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mean3 <- par[3]
mean2 <- mean3 + par[2]
mean1 <- mean2 + par[1]
```

then constrain par's to be positive

Comment: I would precise that the optimization algorithm allowing to constrain the positivity is the one provided by the option `method = "L-BFGS-B"`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent is correct.  `optim` only implements Nelder-Mead without constrants. 
 Nelder-Mead can be implemented in the `nloptr` package with function `neldermead` with box constraints.

Comment: No, `method = "L-BFGS-B"` is an optimization algorithm with box constraints. This is an option of `optim`.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean: the OP said he/she wants Nelder-Mead. I didn't pay attention.